# Pegar valor de um campo pelo id e colocar em uma variável

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Olá, tenho um campo em um formulário que recebe o `id: "teste"`, como posso pegar via `javascript` esse valor e colocar em uma variável??

Encontrei o seguinte na internet

```
var str = document.getElementById("teste").value;
```

Mas isso me traz valor `undefined`, existe alguma outra maneira?

Meu formulário:

```
<div class="divFormulario">
            @(Html.DevExtreme().Form<FormaPagamentoViewModel>
    ()
    .ID("formularioCadastro")
    .ShowValidationSummary(false)
    .Items(items =>
    {
    items.AddGroup()
    .Items(groupItems =>
    {
       groupItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.Fpg_quantidade)
      .Editor(e => e.NumberBox().ID("teste").Width("70px").OnKeyPress("key_press").OnEnterKey("enter")); 
    })
    .FormData(Model)
    )

</div>

<script>
 function enter() {
     str = document.getElementById("teste").value;
  }
</script>
```

Página inspecionada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Posta o seu HTML

Comment: Posta seu HTML e o que tentou com JavaScript

Comment: Não sei o que é DOM, meu html está ai

Comment: Em javascript eu só quero colocar em uma variável o valor, só isso

Comment: Pronto, era isso?

Comment: Perdão, postei a versão errada, utilizei `.value` msm

Comment: Vai inspecionar elementos do navegador e veja como ficou o HTML do campo.

Comment: Pronto, postei em foto pq fica mais fácil de entender

Comment: @Sam na resposta do user139742 eu mostro o que retorno quando faço `innerHTML`, fica mais fácil de entender

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está usando `DevExtreme`, andei pesquisando e seria melhor você utilizar `onValueChanged` ao invez de `onEnterKey`, pois sempre que o valor é alterado a função é executada

https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxAutocomplete/Configuration/#onValueChanged

Basta você fazer:

```
<div class="divFormulario">
            @(Html.DevExtreme().Form<FormaPagamentoViewModel>
    ()
    .ID("formularioCadastro")
    .ShowValidationSummary(false)
    .Items(items =>
    {
    items.AddGroup()
    .Items(groupItems =>
    {
       groupItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.Fpg_quantidade)
      .Editor(e => e.NumberBox().ID("teste").Width("70px").OnKeyPress("key_press").onValueChanged("enter")); 
    })
    .FormData(Model)
    )

</div>

<script>
 function enter(e) { //Tem que passar e como parâmetro 
     str = e.value; //Aqui pega o valor que foi digitado
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode tentar algo assim:

**HTML:**

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="text" id="inputId" />
    <input type="submit" id="submitId" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
// Função que mostra o valor do input num alert
function mostrarValor() {
    alert(document.getElementById("inputId").value);
}

// Evento que é executado toda vez que uma tecla for pressionada no input
document.getElementById("inputId").onkeypress = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        mostrarValor();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}

// Evento que é executado ao clicar no botão de enviar
document.getElementById("submitId").onclick = function(e) {
    mostrarValor();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: O meu problema é que ao fazer  `document.getElementById("inputId").value` ele me retorna undefined, talvez seja algo no meu html

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você está tentando pegar o value de uma div.

divs não tem valores, apenas input, textarea e outros elementos que recebem a entrada do usuário.

Se você quer recuperar o HTML interno da div, utilize

```
document.getElementById("teste").innerHTML;
```

Ou se quiser recuperar apenas o texto, sem as declarações de possíveis tags, utilize

```
document.getElementById("teste").innerText;
```

Comment: `innerText` me retorna `""` e  `innerHTML` me retorna tudo, porém me mostra o valor correto, como posso pegar o valor ?

Comment: `"<input type="hidden" value="15" name="Fpg_quantidade"><div class="dx-texteditor-container">...` innerHTML me retorna isso, e eu queria apenas o campo value

Answer (score 0):

Você deve atribuir o ID que você quer pegar em alguma string html.

Por exemplo:

```
<p id="teste">Algum texto de exemplo</p>
```

Comment: Eu fiz isso, faltou postar, desculpe